# Firebase: How Can Newlines Be inserted Into Strings?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a JSON file to maintain my readonly data and am using the Firebase Console (console.firebase.google.com) to import that data into my Firebase database. I am using the Firebase frameworks for iOS to retrieve that data and display it in my iOS application. Within the data I have strings that I am displaying in UITextViews. How can I insert newlines into the strings?